# (Wpf) Разные панели для разных групп GroupStyle

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть стиль для `ItemsControl` в котором указывается стиль для группировки элементов:

```
<ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        <GroupStyle.Panel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.Panel>
    </GroupStyle>
</ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
```

И соответственно в коде выставляются группировки:

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.DataContext).GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Group"));
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.DataContext).GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("CreateDate"));
```

Собственно группировка работает, но требуется чтобы первая группа ориентировалась по горизонтали, а вторая по вертикали. Подскажите как решить данный вопрос.

Comment: Триггером пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал, свойство Panel не является свойством зависимости

Comment: У вас в разметке есть `StackPanel`, пробовали в нее триггер добавить?

Comment: хорошо, попробую

Comment: других вариантов нет?

Comment: Собственно, если определять триггер в StackPanel, то он не срабатывает так как в ее DataContext находятся данные списка, а не группа GroupItem. Соответственно нет чего проверять